# pushViewController leads to a black screen

Tags: iphone, ios, pushviewcontroller

I have an iOS project (not using Storyboards) that has 2 UITextField and 1 button (a login screen). When the user clicks the button, it launches a POST to the server that returns "1" if the user is in the database. And, then, goes to another screen.

The problem is, that screen show black. This is my code:

In requestFinished method:

```
if([responseString2 isEqualToString:(@"1")]){
termsViewController *termscreen=[[termsViewController alloc]init];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:termscreen animated:YES];
}
```

In the delegate class, in the method initDiddidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.viewController = [[firstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"firstViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
//
UINavigationController *navcontroller= [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
[[self window]setRootViewController:navcontroller];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];    
return YES;

}
```

It goes to another screen, shows the navigation bar...but the screen is black. I am new to iphone developing, so probably will be missing something.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does "termsViewController" has a nib file, does it have anything in that nib file?

Comment: Yes Omar, its full with stuff like a UIScrollView, UILabels, UIButtons...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are not assigning the nib file with it. Try this:

```
termsViewController *termscreen=[[termsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"termsViewController" bundle:nil];
```

I assume your view controller variable's name to be `termsViewController`, which you may change to fit your needs.  I hope this helps.  Happy coding :-)

Comment: I have done that, Anshuk, and it now throws "'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle". I have veryfied that the target is set properly (in the inspector)is correct, also set the Location from "Relative to group" to "Relative to project", and throws the same exception.

Comment: This is the initWithNibName method in termsViewController, in case it helps:- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

Comment: why are u creating initWithNibName method? just create a xib file and name it termsViewController. then call the statement mentioned above.

Comment: I didn't created that method, was created by the Xcode when created the project. Should i delete it?

Comment: it doesnt create on my side. though i hv not worked on ios5.0 yet. may ios5.0 creates on its own. u can try removing it. mayb it helps

Comment: It's commented now, and it now throws: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "terms" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

Comment: Ok, i linked the File's Owner with the view in the .xib file and now it works. Thank you very much to you all, people!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this happened because your second view controller is not inside the navigation controller. When you create a nav controller you have to add an array of objects to it, so it knows what to push.

Code snippet:

```
UINavigationController *navContr = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
FirstViewController *firstViewContr = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
MapViewController *mapContr = [[MapViewController alloc] init];
NSArray *vcArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: mapContr, firstViewContr, nil];
[navContr setViewControllers:vcArray];
[self.window setRootViewController:navContr];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Answer (score -2):

Could be that you didn't implement (or deleted) the

```
- (void)loadView
{
    // If you create your views manually, you MUST override this method and use it to create your views.
    // If you use Interface Builder to create your views, then you must NOT override this method.
}
```

Comment: My loadView method was as the one you have posted. I have tried to comment it, and the result is the same.